# dtoverlay=gpio-shutdown,gpio_pull=off

Tags: pi-3, rpi.gpio, pi-3a+

I was wondering if utilizing the code below would be sufficient in shutting down and restarting a Raspberry Pi 3 A+ with the use of a TTP223 capacitive touch sensor. By default, the touch sensor is outputting high and when touched, outputs logic low. Since it outputs high, I figured using "gpio_pull=off" would be appropriate.

`dtoverlay=gpio-shutdown,gpio_pull=off`

Answer (score 0):

That should work, assuming your touch sensor is connected to the default `gpio_pin=3`. Note that even if you disable the internal pull resistors, there are still external 1.8k pullup resistors for I²C on GPIO pins 2 and 3 ([schematic](https://www.raspberrypi.org/app/uploads/2018/11/Raspberry_Pi_3A_schematics.pdf)), but they won't come close to exceeding the output current of your TTP223.

Comment: Ah yeah, I figured gpio_pull=off would be pointless with that pin. For safety, I am trying a new code as follows: `dtoverlay=gpio-shutdown,gpio_pin=4,active_low=1,gpio_pull=off`